# Google map and controls disabled, markers/ anything on map cannot be clicked

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a web page with a google map and during development the google map controls suddenly stopped working. I suspect this might caused by the wrong css or JS. I have included the relevant code here below. Please advice me on how to get the map active again so users can drag the map and also click on markers/ map.

My HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="map-position">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="" class="overlap ">

    <text style="vertical-align:top;text-align:center; font-weight:bold">Load Itineraries Test</text>
    <hr>
    <div id="floating-panel">
        <span>Select an Itenarary From the List Below: </span>
        <ul id="itin_list" class="list-group">
    </div>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html { 
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#map_canvas {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    float: bottom;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute
}
.overlap {
    position: relative; 
    height: 80%; 
    width: 30%;
    margin: auto;
    float: right;
    border: 2px solid #3399FF; 
    background: white;
    top: 55px;
    right: 5px
}
.map-position {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: -1;
}



#directions-panel {
        margin-top: 5px;
        background-color: #FFEE77;
        padding: 10px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height:200px;
        z-index: 9900;
}
```

Javascript (for map only)

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(7.450907, 80.808975),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `position: fixed` from the `.map-position` class

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/22cok71m/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(7.450907, 80.808975),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  // directionsDisplay.setMap(map);


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  float: bottom;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute
}
.overlap {
  position: relative;
  height: 80%;
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  float: right;
  border: 2px solid #3399FF;
  background: white;
  top: 55px;
  right: 5px
}
.map-position {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* position: fixed;*/
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="map-position">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="" class="overlap ">
    <text style="vertical-align:top;text-align:center; font-weight:bold">Load Itineraries Test</text>
    <hr>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <span>Select an Itenarary From the List Below: </span>

      <ul id="itin_list" class="list-group" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```